# Garbage Disposal Shoots Contents Upward

Tags: garbage-disposal

Can't find anything that matches this particular issue on Google or here.

Our sink has a garbage disposal that is about 5 years old.  For about the last six months or so, the unit tends to propel its contents (water and waste) upward.  This sometimes happens immediately when it is turned on, but usually it will happen after a few seconds of grinding.

Is this a common symptom of a damaged/older disposal unit, or is this "normal" behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is one of two things:

1) Damaged splash guard (the rubber flap pieces that hang from the drain)

2) Some object, or some mass of shredded food/etc, has become lodged in the disposal so when it's spinning, things hit and just get shot upward.

Both could be a long shot, but it's worth checking in to both for sure.

Comment: I second checking the splash guard.

Comment: From experience...I'd say it's the 2nd option.

Answer (score 7):

It could also be caused by a partially blocked drain pipe.

Comment: This matches precisely with *usually it will happen after a few seconds of grinding*